# Decode a java serialized .dat file in C

Tags: java, c, serialization

Is it possible to decode a java serialized .dat file in **C**?

I have a file in a java project which I read as follows in java project:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(.dat file path);
ObjectInputStream si = new ObjectInputStream(in);
si.readUTF();

si.readBoolean()
int num=si.readInt();
```

How can I convert this code to **C**? I know the first character is a utf character, the second one is boolean and the third is int.

```
unsigned char buf[16];
FILE *fp = fopen((const char*)[filePath UTF8String], "rb");
fread(buf, 4, 1, fp); // read 4 bytes
printf("%s", buf);
```

Comment: Simple, just read byte for byte. As far as I know for Java: UTF = 4 bytes, Boolean = 1 byte, Int = 4 bytes. But you'll have to write out the data and make sure that's the size of the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The official Javadocs for the `DataInput` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) specify exactly what `readUTF`, `readBoolean`, and `readInt` read from the stream. Just implement those in C, following the descriptions exactly, and you'll be fine.

I see you're using Objective-C; for `readUTF` in particular you can construct NSString after you've read the appropriate number of bytes using `[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:byteArray length:length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`.

By the way, your Java code is being wasteful: it is using an `ObjectInputStream` when it really only needs a `DataInputStream`, which is much simpler and provides the same methods you're using. (This came to my notice in particular because if you *had* been using the intended functionality of `ObjectInputStream`, i.e. reading *serialized Java objects*, then it would be *much harder* to write decoding in C, because the format is much more complex and designed for use by systems which include the Java standard libraries.)